# OAuth / Identity Server allow Server to Server communication not on behalf of a user

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, identityserver4

All,

I have multiple application servers I want to change over from our existing authentication/authorization. I'd like to allow the following two options:

1. Ability for users to allow applications access to their resources, this can be easily achieved using IdentityServer and I'm confident I can set this up with ease
2. Allow two of my application servers to retrieve data from each other base on APIKey/ApiSecret only and **not** on behalf of a user, these servers should not have restricted access to any of the data. Where as #1 would be restricted based on scopes/claims.

Will OAuth/IdentityServer allow #2? If so, how?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. Set up a client_credentials client with all the resource scopes required to access the data you're talking about. The client_credentials grant type is perfect for this situation.